# Compilation problem for custom code when upgrading to DNN 9.12

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to update my code to make it compatible with DNN 9.12.0 but I'm facing the following error:
SGEN : error CS0012: The type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

First, I changed the project references to use the DNN 9.12.0 assemblies and I configured the project compilation to target Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.2.
I tried to add a reference to the netstandard assembly with no success.

If someone has already encountered this problem and managed to resolve, I'll appreciate your help.